# Como transformar uma data padrão inglês em uma data padrão brasileiro no R?

Tags: r, data

Suponhamos que tenho uma data no formato padrão inglês ano-mês-dia (ymd):

```
data = Sys.Date()

print(data)
[1] "2019-12-03"
```

Mas na verdade necessito que esta data esteja no formato padrão brasileiro dia/mês/ano:

```
print(data_BR)

[1] "03/12/2019"
```

Como posso transformar a minha data padrão inglês em uma data padrão brasileiro no R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar a formatação.

`format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y")`

[Fonte](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já havia usado a função `format`, mas eu a usei de forma errada. Mas agora funcionou perfeitamente.